# Any disadvantage of using $(document).on( 'click', ,,)

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, dom

Is there any disadvantage of using `$(document).on('click',...,function)` EDIT: [I meant  $(document).on('click', #xyz ,function)`]over`$('#xyz').click(function)`??

Especially I do find it very useful in pages where I have to use partial views with controls. I do call  `$(document).on ()'s` together with document.ready even before the partial view exists and when I get the partial view I don't have to rewire events.

However I am wondering is there any drawback of this approach?

Thanks

Comment: clicking anywhere on the document will call the function while $(#) will target a specific element

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

If you add the event handler to `document`, it will have to handle all the events, even those you don't want to handle.

Instead of `document`, when delegating events always use the container nearest to the targets.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in the event bubbling. From a performance point of view, the former is much better in instances where there are a ton of elements needing to be bound.

```
<ul id="list">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  ... a thousand more <li>'s
  </ul>
```

In this case `$('#list').on('click', 'li', function() { });` would be much better than `$('li').click(function() { });` . It's the difference between 1 event and 1 million and 2 events. I would also advise against binding these elements to the document unless you have no choice. The fastest selector would be bound to an ID.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click',...,function )
```

will register a click event on the entire document, so clicking anywhere on the page will trigger it.

```
$('#xyz').click(function)
```

will register a trigger on just the element with id=xyz